# Did Optimus' creator actually get his message that "he was coming for them"?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-the-last-knight

So, at the end of *Transformers: Age of Extinction* we learn that Optimus Prime went searching for his "creator" and the movie ends there.

> There are mysteries to the universe we were never meant to solve. But who we are and why we are here are not among them. Those answers we carry inside. I am Optimus Prime. Leave planet Earth alone. 'Cause I'm coming for you.
>
> <sub>[Script from Springfield](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=transformers-age-of-extinction)</sub>

Fast forward to *Transformers: The Last Knight* where we learn that,

> Optimus does indeed find his "creator", who is Quintessa, on Cybertron.

> It seems to me that it was a strange coincidence for Quintessa to have been waiting for Optimus on Cybertron. **Did she actually get Optimus' message that "he was coming for his creator(s)"?**

---

<sub>No YouTube video for the particular scene is out yet, nor is the official script; will edit when one is created. For now:</sub>

> [image: Optimus captured]

Comment: Here it is [Optimus Prime meets Quintessa](https://youtu.be/bcRdtucrxQo?t=45)